# Dynamic Jquery Sortable Issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using [Jquery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/). php MySql

I have used click event on the respective item's of the Sortable, to retrieve the respective images from the DB. And also I am using AJAX to get the item names from DB.

**First Thing** - The list item of the Sortable is refreshing everytime when I click the item.,due to the ajax. How to  prevent the list refreshing, So that I can store the **order** of the list in DB.

**Second Thing** -  I wanted to change the background color of the Clicked Item.

```
$( "#Sortable" ).sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            update: function (event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mypage.php'
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();


       });
```